# Allow two roles to execute commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a `discord.js bot` that should be used only by people with a certain role. I have the actual server and a test server and I was wondering if I can allow **two** roles to execute commands.

I am currently changing the role manually in the code and it's not particularly user-friendly.

Here's the code:

```
const { role1, role2 } = require('./config.json');
const role = role1

client.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.member.roles.cache.has(role)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

        try {
            client.commands.get(commandName).execute(message, args);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            message.reply(`There was an error`);
    }

    } else {
        message.reply('You don't have access to this command!')
    }
    
})
```

I tried using logical OR (`||`) but doesn't seem to work as it only allows the first role written to execute commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow the user to execute the command if he has `Role1` OR `Role2` `message.member.roles.cache.has(role)` can be replaced with `message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>[Role1, Role2].includes(r.id))` like so (assuming that `Role1` and `Role2` are IDs and not the name of the role).

```
const { role1, role2 } = require('./config.json');

client.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>[role1, role2].includes(r.id))) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

        try {
            client.commands.get(commandName).execute(message, args);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            message.reply(`There was an error`);
    }

    } else {
        message.reply('You don't have access to this command!')
    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this in my `message event`:

```
// This is for demonstration because I'm defining 'requiredRoles' in every command file
    let roleCount = 0;
    let missingRole = '';

    // Ensure the user has the required roles
    for (const requiredRole of requiredRoles) {
        const role = guild.roles.cache.find(
            r => r.name === requiredRole,
        );

        if (role && member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
            roleCount++;
        }
        else {
            missingRole = requiredRole;
        }
    }
    
    if(roleCount === 0 && requiredRoles.length > 0) {
        return message.reply(
            `You are missing the "${requiredRole}" role to use this command!`,
        );
    }
```

**Explanation:**

A loop is started which runs through all `roles`. If a `user` belongs to a `role`, `roleCount` is increased by 1. If it does **not** belong to the `role` of the current run, this `role` is written to `missingRole`.

When the loop is finished, it checks if the user has **at least** one of the required `roles`. If **not**, an error `message` is returned.

Comment: The bot should allow the user to execute the command if he has Role1 OR Role2, not both

Comment: Sorry. I edited it, this should do it now

Comment: It works only for the first role written, Test1 for reference

Comment: So if the user has the roles `Test1` **and** `Test2` he is not allowed to execute the command?

Comment: I figured out how to do it thanks to an old answer you gave. I did not express myself good enough, sorry

Comment: Did the exact answer from earlier work or did you have to adjust it? Then I would paste my original answer again

Comment: It worked, I just answered my own question. Thanks for the help